# ElasticSearch: can not connect to host

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastica

I try populate elastic storage with 1 000 000 documents. This data loads from database (PostgreSQL). And i have a error after write 28K documents:

```
  [Elastica\Exception\Connection\HttpException]  
  Couldn't connect to host, Elasticsearch down?
```

Save logic: check document if exists, and insert if not exists, and update if exists.

In result, sends 54K Requests before throw exception.

I try a set `ulimit` and `net.core.somaxconn` to max value, but not working. I think it's a mistake ElasticSearch.

OS: Debian

API Client: https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica

What could be the problem?

Thank.

**UPD:** Elastic search work with default configuration.

Comment: where did you set up your Elasticsearch server? update with `curl es-server:9200` result.

Comment: did you check the log at Elasticsearch side? may be there were some errors there that led to its crash? Also, how do you communicate with Elasticsearch, what is the way you send your requests? Last but not least, which version of Elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: Log is empty, only `notice` records